# Clases estáticas frente a dinámicas

Tags: c#

Buenas noches compañeros.
Llevo apenas unos meses con el lenguaje orientado a objetos de C#.
Me encuentro ejemplos en los que utilizan clases estáticas y no sé muy bien porque. La teoría, en principio la conozco, unas hace falta instanciarlas y las otras no, pero, ¿Cuando debo crear una clase como static y porque? Y la siguiente pregunta, cuando en una clase dinámica quiero acceder a métodos propios dentro de la misma clase, con el this.metodo(), por qué en las estáticas esto no funciona así?
¿En una estática hace falta que todos sus métodos y atributos sean también estáticos?

Intento encontrarle una lógica pero no me queda del todo claro...

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya te lo mencionaron, una clase *estática* simplemente está ahí, esperando que utilices sus funciones. Esto es, en el código nunca la inicias, sino que simplemente puedes llamar a sus funciones. Por ejemplo:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32("15");
```

La clase [`Convert`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,fc990bd1275d43d6) es una clase estática, no necesitas nada como

```
Convert convert = new Convert();
int x = convert.ToInt32("15");
```

para que funcione el método [`ToInt32`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,069d595792a157df) ni ningún otro. Como no existe ninguna instancia, no puedes tener variables ni propiedades ahí, solo funciones.

> ¿Cuando debo crear una clase como static y porque? [sic]

Cuando consideres necesario. Un ejemplo puede ser crear una biblioteca de funciones que vayas a usar frecuentemente en tu código, una que tengo de ejemplo es:

```
public static string ToShortString(DateTime Fecha)
{
    int _mes = Fecha.Month;
    string Mes = 1 == _mes ? "ENE" : 2 == _mes ? "FEB" : 3 == _mes ? "MAR" : 4 == _mes ? "ABR" : 5 == _mes ? "MAY" : 6 == _mes ? "JUN" : 7 == _mes ? "JUL" : 8 == _mes ? "AGO" : 9 == _mes ? "SEP" : 10 == _mes ? "OCT" : 11 == _mes ? "NOV" : "DIC";
    return string.Concat(Fecha.Day, "/", Mes, "/", Fecha.Year);
}
```

que convierte un `DateTime` en un texto del tipo `"21/AGO/2017"`.

> cuando en una clase dinámica quiero acceder a métodos propios dentro de la misma clase, con el this.metodo(), por qué en las estáticas esto no funciona así? ¿En una estática hace falta que todos sus métodos y atributos sean también estáticos?

No funciona porque no existe `this` ya que [`this` es una referencia a la instancia actual de la clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) y ¿recuerdas ese `Convert.ToInt32()` de arriba? Como no hay ninguna instancia funcionando, no hay ninguna instancia de la que puedas extraer métodos, por lo tanto esos métodos también deben ser estáticos.

Answer (score 5):

El cuando, es una pregunta que no tiene respuesta. Cuando debes crearla depende del programa que estés haciendo y como uses las clases.

Las clases estáticas son como librerías de funciones, no necesitas instanciar la clase, en general no tienen propiedades, solo funciones, y en memoria ocupan una sola posición de memoria para toda la clase (hay un solo puntero a la clase).

Todas las funciones de la clase son estáticas, porque al no ser instanciadas en ningún momento, necesitan estar estaticamente en la memoria en un solo lugar. no ocupan espacio de memoria para sus propiedades, ya que hay una sola instancia global a la misma.

Entonces dicho esto, en general las clases estáticas se usan para tener una librería de funciones que puedes acceder desde cualquier parte de tu programa.

Comment: Gracias gbianchi, ¿Es por esto por lo que la palabra clave "this." al llamar a su propio método no tiene sentido aquí? ¿Porque es la única instancia de clase? (por llamarlo de alguna manera)

Answer (score 3):

Siguiendo el paradigma de programación a objetos deberías utilizar clases estáticas lo menos posible ya que son simplemente bibliotecas de funciones tal y como dice `gbianchi` que declaran procedimientos y no objetos.

Al estar estudiando creo que será mucho más adecuado para ti que te olvides de que existen las clases estáticas y trabajes siempre con clases normales. Con el tiempo y viendo donde se usan clases estáticas en .Net (la clase Convert por ejemplo y similares) ya irás viendo donde no hace dañó usarlas.