# ¿Como es posible que las variables de una clase puedan mantener varios valores por cada objeto?

Tags: c#

Tengo una clase definida con los siguientes atributos o variables de tipo id y string

```
 public class Order{
    private int id = 9;
    private string latitudeCustomer = "123211";
    private string longitudeCustomer = "123421";

    public Order(string lat,string long){
       latitudeCustomer = lat;
       longitudeCustomer = long;
    }


    public void printOrder(){
        Console.WriteLine($"{id}{latitudeCustomer}{longitudCustomer}");
    }
 }
```

Luego en el método main, creo una variable del tipo de la clase para almacenar un objeto de ese tipo:

Luego de almacenar el objeto de ese tipo invoco al método que tiene ese objeto...entonces el método puede leer las variables de la clase...igual puedo crear otra variable de tipo Order e invocar al método.

Se puede decir que las dos variables tienen valores diferentes...ambas ejecutan al método y para cada objeto, se imprimen los valores que se pasaron como argumento al constructor, al instanciar cada uno.

```
class Program{

   public static void main(string[] args){
     Order o0 = new Order("45","67");
     Order o1 = new Order("12","14");
     o1.printOrder();  //imprime 9 12 14
     o0.printOrder();  //imprime 9 45 67

   }

}
```

En este caso, constructor asigna dos veces valores a las variables de la clase. pero las dos parejas de valores persisten, no se sostiene un solo valor y me preguntaba como eso era posible. si hiciera publica esas variables y por medio de `o0` hago esto `o0.latitudeCustomer = 98;` el 98 solo se imprime cuando ejecuto el método por medio de `o0` pero para `o1` si leo el valor de esa misma variable siempre queda igual sin sobrescribirse a pesar de que por medio de `o0` `latitudeCustomer` fue asignado el valor `98` a la variable definida en la clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En términos simples, [las clases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/classes-and-objects) son como recetas que le dice al framework cómo crear los objetos.

Cada vez que haces `new Order(...)` o `new CualquierClase(...)` estás creando una **nueva instancia** de esa clase y lo que ocurre es que el framework utiliza un espacio de memoria diferente para almacenar su contenido sin compartirlo con otros objetos aunque sean del mismo tipo (a menos que tenga [miembros estáticos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)). (*Reitero que es una explicación muy simplificada*)

De acuerdo con tu ejemplo:

```
 Order o0 = new Order("45","67");
 Order o1 = new Order("12","14");
```

`o0` y `o1` son dos instancias de la misma clase, cada una ocupa espacios de memoria diferentes y ninguna tiene acceso a los valores de la otra.

Es como tener dos carros de la misma marca y modelo. Ambos fueron creados con la misma receta (dos instancias de la misma clase) pero pueden tener colores diferentes, pueden haber recorrido distinta cantidad de kilómetros y la cantidad de gasolina en sus tanques puede ser diferente (por mencionar algunas propiedades).

Ten en cuenta que también puedes declarar clases [estáticas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) o clases con miembros estáticos (`static ...`) y [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/96243/182188) y sus respuestas pueden servir como punto de partida para investigar al respecto.

Comment: Entonces, cuando por ejemplo escribes una clase con un método y un campo y en el método accedes a ese campo, es como si estuvieses diciendo:

Los objetos de esta clase, individualmente tendrán este método y este atributo y en el método, el objeto usara su atributo. por que en la clase escribiste eso. una función accediendo a una variable. entonces cada objeto cuando se invoque un método de su instancia, agarra su campo y lo usa adentro.

Comment: Eso entendí, agradecería mucho tu juicio para mi primer comentario de esta respuesta...para ver si esta bien mi suposición o no. ya que así podría seguir practicando.

Comment: Si, tu suposición es cierta.